# Control problems in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4, controllers

Starting a couple of days ago, when playing Skyrim when I try to walk forward, every now and then my character tries to move toward the left. Is this likely a problem with my controller? (Doesn’t happen with other games though) or is this a bug in the game; or even my PlayStation?

Comment: Most likely it's a problem with the joystick on your controller. Skyrim doesn't have any issues with characters veering off in random directions. It wouldn't be your console either because your console doesn't influence character movement.

Comment: This happens on PC when you switch from Skyrim to other applications and back, while steering in some direction. But you are on playstation ... like @FoxMcCloud said ... must be the controller

Comment: This happens on PS4 for me after the console has been suspended with the game running. Character will drift right a bit when walking for a short time. It also happens in AC Valhalla so I assume it's to do with the third-party controller I use.

Answer (score 3):

As others said in the comments, it is more than likely your joystick. I actually had a similar problem happen with one of my Xbox 360 controllers. The problem is simply from usage. I am unsure what you could do to stop the problem, other than buy a new controller.

One other thing (if your controller has sentimental value :P) is to take it to a tech repair shop and have it fixed. Game Stop *might* fix it, but more and likely just replace it and say they fixed it.

Comment: No need to buy new controller. Heres a tip to save money and it fixes issue with both buttons not working and analog sticks. Take the controller apart. Usually its an issue with a bad contact. I  use canned air and blow the contacts and then simply put it back together